# save combobox value when manually selected

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

is it possible to write the value of a combobox to a cell but only when a user selects an item from the combobox but not if the userform refreshes and clears the combobox?

Szenario: I have a userform with 3 comboboxes. In these 3 comboboxes, the user chooses 3 items. Below these comboboxes, there is another combobox where the user can yet again chose an item, however, the given items are the previously selected items.

I solved the situation by using combobox.click and save it to the spreadsheet everytime it gets selected. However, if I now refresh the userform the cells get changed to empty and the cells get cleared out (as combobox.click gets triggered by that as well).

Anyone got an Idea?

Although this is mainly a theoretical question, I will be happy to provide any specific code. As my current code is over 2000 lines, it would be a bit much for SO.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a small example app with only a few lines of code and a sample userform with your comboboxes. This does two things:  first, it helps to organize your thoughts and focus your question with code that you can easily post here for us to help; second, when I do this it usually solves my problem my removing all the "extra" 2,000 lines of code and I can see the situation is isolation.

Comment: @PeterT thank you for the tipp! I will try that. I realized my question could be simplified to:

Is there any command that only triggers when a user manually changes a combobox?

When a user changes the selection of the combobox, the entry gets saved to the excel sheet. But I also have the scenario where the comobox gets emptied automatically - the .click command gets triggered then as well although it should not..